# Spring MVC 3: Why the view is not displayed?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I work with Spring MVC 3 and i don't understand why my view is not displaying. Here my controller :

```
@Controller
public class ProjectController extends BaseController {



    @RequestMapping(value="/searchprojects/{keywords}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView findProjectsFullTextSearch(HttpSession session,@PathVariable String keywords){
         ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

         List<Project> projectsList =  projectServices.findProjectByFullTextSearch(keywords);
        if(projectsList!=null && projectsList.size()>0){
             modelAndView.addObject("projectsList", projectsList);
        }

         modelAndView.setViewName("resultSearch");


         return modelAndView;
    } 

..... others methods
}
```

Tiles configurations:

```
<definition name="resultSearch" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="resultSearch" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/project/resultSearch.jsp" />
</definition>
```

My view is not displayed and i don't understand. Here are the log http://pastebin.com/4symuGWt .The problem just appear in this view. Other work !

Comment: change value attribute of `<put-attribute name="title" value="resultSearch" />` , this will go recursive loop.

Comment: I've found the response. My request was done in Ajax. And Ajax send the response ( html page ) to the js request as a response and DOES NOT REDIRECT TO view.

Comment: while using AJAX don't return ModelAndView, return data. in your case projectsList. and put @ResponseBody just before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i explain it in the comment.  My request was done using Ajax. And Ajax send the response ( html page ) to the view as content and does not redirect to view as i was thinking. So i've changed my ajax call to a form with submit button.